# How to print outside of Main Argument? (It can be done)

Tags: printing, program-entry-point

This is how you print outside of main.

```
public class PrintOutsideMain {

    static {System.out.println ("You can go with this");}


    public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Or This is where its at");

    }

}
```

It works

```
run:
You can go with this
Or This is where its at
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Something I was looking for a while ago but I played around and found I could do this. I could not find an answer for this question so I chose to post it. I also did not find any information as to why it is not a good practice to do. I was never taught it was a bad practice to do.

Comment: Completed the question above.